# How to remove padding from angular material datepicker

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to remove the padding value from the following (it is set by default to this value in angular material)

> .mat-form-field-appearance-fill .mat-form-field-flex {
> border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
> padding: .75em .75em 0 .75em; }

I have tried using

> ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-fill .mat-form-field-flex{
> padding: 0px 0px;
> }

but this does not change the padding value.
what can I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to styling Material components, things can get fiddly. I'd advise adding the `!important` flag:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-fill .mat-form-field-flex {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Please mark the question as answered so others can find it!